# Why do I need to increase the amountInMaximum by 1.0001 for a swapExactOutputMultiHop trade or get STF?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3

For a swapExactOutputMultiHop trade on Uniswap if I don't add 1.0001 I get a revert with "STF" which stands for secure transfer failed.

Why is this? I am pulling the amount like so:

```
  let amountInMaximum =
    await params.quoterContract.callStatic.quoteExactOutput(
      helpers.reversedPathPacked,
      ethers.utils.parseEther("2")
    );
  // not using BigNumber right here, but produces the correct output.
  amountInMaximum = BigNumber.from(
    BigInt((amountInMaximum * 1.0001).toFixed(0)).toString()
  );
```

And I am passing the path in reverse as the docs suggest. Thanks